# Show that it is impossible to find $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $ \frac{\sqrt{5}}{10}=a+b \frac{\sqrt{3}}{7} $

Tags: extension-field, irrational-numbers

Show that it is impossible to find $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{5}}{10}=a+b \frac{\sqrt{3}}{7}
$$

We have $\frac{1}{20}=a^{2}+\frac{2 \sqrt{3}}{7} a b+b^{2} \frac{3}{49}=\left(a^{2}+b^{2} \frac{3}{49}\right)+\frac{2 \sqrt{3}}{7} a b$ with $a \neq 0, b \neq 0$.

Suppose $a=0$, then
$$
\frac{1}{20}=b^{2} \frac{3}{49} \Leftrightarrow 3 b^{2}= \frac{49}{20}
$$
(here I don't know how to conclude)

If $b=0$, then
$$
\sqrt{5}=10 a
$$
which is impossible because $\sqrt{5} \neq \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: "here I don't know how to conclude": I know. $b^2=\frac{49}{60}$ has no rational solution.

Comment: From your first row calculation you can conclude that $\sqrt{3}$ must be rational. Go from there rather than worrying about values of $a$ or $b$

Comment: @Paul Yes but I still have to show that $a$ and $b$ are not zero, otherwise the argument that $\sqrt{3}$ is not rational does not hold.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ok but how to show it?

Comment: True, sorry too quick to reply!

Comment: You can say $\sqrt{15}=\frac{7}{2b}$ and if you are happy that $\sqrt{5} \neq \mathbb{Q}$ can you be happy that $\sqrt{15} \neq \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: $3b^{2} = \frac{49}{20} \implies 60b^{2} = 49 \implies 7$ divides $60b^{2}$, but $60$ and $7$ are coprimes, then $7$ divides $b$, as $49 = 7^{2}$ then $49$ divides $b^{2}$, then $60\dot q = 1$, with $q \in \mathbb{Z}$. Is a contradiction.

Comment: Re my answer, leave question after the answer, if you are unsure about proving that $k\sqrt{5}$ can not be an integer.  As long as your comment is posted after my answer, I will be notified.

Comment: This is same as proving that there are no rationals $a, b$ with $\sqrt{5}=a+b\sqrt{3}$. You should get an easy contradiction by squaring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Show that it is impossible to find $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that
> $$
> \frac{\sqrt{5}}{10}=a+b \frac{\sqrt{3}}{7}
> $$

Alternative approach.

**Lemma 1** 
$\sqrt{15}$ is not a rational number.

$\underline{\text{Proof}}$

Suppose that $~\displaystyle \sqrt{15} = \frac{p}{q} ~:$ 
$~p,q~$ relatively prime integers, and $~q > 0.$ 
Then $q\sqrt{15} = p \implies 15q^2 = p^2.$ 
However, since $p,q$ relatively prime, this implies that $15$ divides $p^2$.  However, by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, this implies that the prime factorization of $p$ contains both $3$ and $5$.

This implies that $15$ divides $p$.  
This implies that $(15)^2$ divides $p^2.$ 
This implies that $(15)$ divides $q^2,~$ since $15q^2 = p^2.$ 
This is a contradiction, because $p,q$ are relatively prime.

**Lemma 2** 
If $~k \in \Bbb{Z_{\neq 0}},~$ then $k\sqrt{15}$ is not an integer.

$\underline{\text{Proof}}$

Suppose $k\sqrt{15} = n \in \Bbb{Z}.$ 
Then $~\displaystyle ~\sqrt{15} = \frac{n}{k}.$ 
This contradicts Lemma 1.

**Lemma 3** 
If $R,S \in \Bbb{Z_{\neq 0}}$, 
then $R\sqrt{3} + S\sqrt{5}$ is not an integer.

$\underline{\text{Proof}}$

Suppose $~R\sqrt{3} + S\sqrt{5} = n \in \Bbb{Z}.$ 
Then $3R^2 + 5S^2 + 2RS\sqrt{15} = n^2,$ which is also an integer. 
This implies that $2RS\sqrt{15}$ is an integer. 
This contradicts Lemma 2.

---

Suppose that $~\displaystyle a,b =  \frac{p_a}{q_a}, \frac{p_b}{q_b}~$ respectively, 
where $p_a,q_a$ are relatively prime integers, 
where $p_b,q_b$ are relatively prime integers, 
and $q_a, q_b$ are both positive.

Then

$$\frac{p_a}{q_a} + \left(\frac{p_b}{q_b}\times \frac{\sqrt{3}}{7}\right) - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{10} = 0.\tag1 $$

In (1) above, you can ensure that each term has the common denominator of $(q_a \times q_b \times 7 \times 10).$

This implies that

$$\frac{70p_aq_b + 10q_ap_b\sqrt{3} - 7q_aq_b\sqrt{5}}{q_a \times q_b \times 7 \times 10} = 0. $$

This implies that

$$70p_aq_b + 10q_ap_b\sqrt{3} - 7q_aq_b\sqrt{5} = 0. $$

This implies that

$$\left(10q_ap_b\sqrt{3} - 7q_aq_b\sqrt{5}\right) ~~\text{is an integer}.  $$

This is a contradiction, by Lemma 3.

**Edit**
I overlooked that you could have $p_b = 0$. 
However, this would result in $7q_aq_b\sqrt{5}$ being an integer.

The exact same analysis used in Lemmas 1 through 3 may be repeated on $\sqrt{5}$ to show that that would be impossible.

Comment: Nice answer +1!